# Deliver a parameter from betweenness_centrality in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

When using the `betweenness_centrality(G, k=None, normalized=True, weight=None, endpoints=False, seed=None)`, how could I give the parameter `weight` form a graph `G(G=nx.graph())`?

```
betweenness_weight_dic={}
betweenness_weight_dic=nx.closeness_centrality(G,weight='weight')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have edge attributes and pass the name of the edge attribute to the betweenness centrality function, which use the weights for calculating the shortest path. A small example:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
# add edge with the implicit edge attributes weight
g.add_weighted_edges_from([(1,2,3), (2,3,4), (2,5,2), (3,6,4), (6,1,2)])
print(nx.betweenness_centrality(g))
# {1: 0.16666666666666666, 2: 0.5833333333333333, 3: 0.16666666666666666, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.08333333333333333}
print(nx.betweenness_centrality(g,weight="weight"))
# {1: 0.3333333333333333, 2: 0.5, 3: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.16666666666666666}
``
```